# NSTextField - Subclassing & drawRect cause text not to load

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Trying to round out the border of an NSTextField (the little black box in the upper-left corner): http://cl.ly/image/2V2L1u3b3u0G

So I subclassed NSTextField:

MYTextField.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface HATrackCounterField : NSTextField
@end
```

MYTextField.m

```
#import "HATrackCounterField.h"
@implementation HATrackCounterField
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {}
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor blackColor] setFill];
    [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:dirtyRect xRadius:3.0 yRadius:3.0] fill];
}

@end
```

Now its not showing the text-field text: http://cl.ly/image/1J2W3K431C04

I'm new at objective-c, it seems like this should be easy, so I'm probably just doing something wrong...

Thanks!

Note: I'm setting the text through a collection view, and I've tried `setStringValue:` at different points also to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your text-field's text isn't showing because you overwrite `-drawRect` and don't call `[super drawRect:dirtyRect]` in it.

In your case, I think the easiest way to do what you want is using clip mask: just let `NSTextField` perform drawing ant then clip the region:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:dirtyRect xRadius:3.0 yRadius:3.0] setClip];
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

In general it is better to subclass `NSTextFieldCell` instead to make custom drawing, because cells are responsible for drawing.

Comment: Yes, but you should overwrite `-drawWithFrame:inView:` of `NSCell` instead of `-drawRect:`.

Answer (score 3):

For reference for future readers, this is probably how you should do it, by subclassing `NSTextFieldCell`:

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {
    NSBezierPath *betterBounds = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cellFrame xRadius:CORNER_RADIUS yRadius:CORNER_RADIUS];
    [betterBounds addClip];
    [super drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
    if (self.isBezeled) { // optional, but provides an example of drawing a prettier border
        [betterBounds setLineWidth:2];
        [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.510 green:0.643 blue:0.804 alpha:1] setStroke];
        [betterBounds stroke];
    }
}
```

I draw an additional bluish border here (though that seems to be unnecessary for your black box)